# How to detect network delay between two hosts by DNS protocol?

Tags: dns

```
  H1------------------H2
   \                  /
    \                /
     \              /
      \            /
          x (me)
```

Suppose I'm in the point x, and there're two arbitrary host points, H1, H2. I can get the delay between H1 and me by ping, same I can also get the delay between H2 and me by ping (because there's time stamp), the question is, how to get the delay between H1 and H2 using DNS protocol?

Comment: I asked this question for my friend.  Actually I don't know the background of this question.

Comment: You can tell him that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: My friend insist it could and MUST be done with DNS related protocols.

This is a assignment of her colleague course.

Comment: What does she mean by "DNS related protocols"? Which protocols does she consider related to DNS?

Comment: Something to keep in mind here is that DNS requests are UDP; only zone transfers between DNS servers uses TCP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this: define H1 as the authoratative nameserver for some domain, then ask H2 to resolve that domain. Then time the resolve (perhaps with an "I don't know" response) and subtract ping time to H2.

P.S. Tell your friend that cheaters never prosper.

EDITED to remove my claim that this was idiotic. I think this question isn't senseless after all - remember that this is an academic exercise. It may not be very practical, but I think it might be possible, and maybe through my solution. (Triangulating is probably a better idea in general, but it requires machines in the right places.)

Also, yes, I should have mentioned that this requires both machines to be running DNS servers. Probably there's no solution using DNS that does not, however. This question is second-hand and may have originally had that stipulation.

Comment: This is only possible if both machines are running DNS servers.

Comment: True, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: My friend said your answer is correct.  And she said this is not cheating because her teacher allowed them to discuss this question.  Thanks a lot any way!

Comment: I withdraw my sanctimonious comment, in that case. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Her question makes no sense.

DNS is used to turn hostnames (eg, `google.com` or `sstatic.net`) into IP addresses (eg, `64.233.169.104` or `69.59.196.213`).

It has nothing to do with the physical location or network connectivity of individual servers.

In general, it's not possible to determine the link speed between two arbitrary servers remotely.  If you can connect to one of the servers and make it ping the other one directly, you can get their link speed that way, but otherwise, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First off,  **DNS can absolutely *NOT* provide any clue here**.
**Edit**: [following Grumdrig's remark] ... other than the the clues associated with the timing of DNS messages to perform a round trip to these servers.  What I mean by the original statement is that **there is nothing intrinsic to the DNS protocol that makes it more suited for this purpose than say HTTP, ICMP, FTP or whatever protocol** may cause the server to return some message.

Second, the easy way to do this is to have software/access, *directly* on either H1 or H2, but I'm assuming that's the spirit of the question really is:

**How can we *estimate* the delay between H1 and H2, *without having direct access to either host*?**

An ***estimation*** can be done, by using the readings (timing and routes) between H1 or H2 and **several workstations** (not just one).  (as well as having the routes between these many workstations).

This process would be *akin to triangulating* for finding distances or positions in a plain 2D or 3D euclidean space, but of course, remembering that

- network routes are dynamic (unlike segments in geometry)
- distances are not so linear ;-)

**Another possible trick** to estimate this distance is available, in a special case:
 - if H1 or H2 happens to be a server which can be queried from a third location
and 
 - if this server requires the services of the other host to honor such request.

For example if H1 is a web server which uses a webservices located on H2 to produce a particular web page.  By taking multiple measurements for such requests to H1, and by deducting the distance/delay between H1 and our workstation, we can probably estimate the distance/delay between H1 and H2.  We need to be careful to

- take multiple measurements for the purpose of averaging many factors, including the non-network portions of the this chain (say the time it takes for the web server to parse the request, crunch some numbers whatever...)
- take into various possibilities such as possible caching etc...
- estimate the non-network related portion of the chain

A special case of this special case, is if by chance H1 [or H2] is on the very route between the third point and H2 [or H1]. In that case, and assuming that the ICMP packets associated with traceroute are not filtered/stopped on the way, a simple traceroute would answer the question.  This situation is however relatively unlikely...

Comment: I don't agree that it's impossible for DNS to be any help.

Comment: @Grumdrig, see my edit.  The point is that DNS in of itself isn't any more useful for that purpose than any other protocol which prompts the server to return a message.

Comment: But only a protocol that can convince H1 to talk to H2 and report back is going to be of help here. I don't see how to do this with an HTTP request, for example. And in any case, the question stipulated that DNS should be used. And that's not to say that triangulating isn't a good idea, just that that's not what the question was looking for.

Comment: @Grumdrig, agreed, DNS has this characteristics of allowing one to "force" a server to send an request to another one.  Never the less this problem is very contrived, as it implies that both boxes are effectively honoring DNS requests, and that H1 would readily "know" that H2 is authority for the said domain and that yet it would not yet have cached the particular DNS entry (or the absence thereof), etc. etc.  In practical terms, setting up such an experiment is fraught with hurdles

Comment: @mjv I quite agree. Very contrived.